# "Debugger: Error calculating Dart framesError: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'type' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: type"

Tags: flutter

Getting error

"Debugger: Error calculating Dart framesError: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'type' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: type"

while debugging in flutter web.

I have no clue why this happening. I cant understand what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Run` or `Restart` your app instead of Hot Reload.